# Getting key and value from a list containing JSON

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm having issues getting a key and a value from a list in Python. The list itself contains a number of JSON lines structured as follows:

```
[{"values":"test","cost":"1234"},{"values":"test2","cost":"12345"}]
```

The issue is I would ideally not want to convert it to a dictionary as it would mean either populating one during the reading of the original JSON file and appending each JSON piece to a list and then the list to the dictionary.

I found I can print the keys simply by doing this:

```
        for line in file:
            mylist.append(json.loads(line))
            for line in mylist:
                for key in line.keys():
                    print(key)
```

This is again is all fine and it prints all the keys such as the example, "values","test" etc. But I cannot access the values of each by doing this as I would with a dictionary:

```
        for line in file:
            mylist.append(json.loads(line))
            for line in mylist:
                for key,value in line.keys():
                    print(value)
```

As this throws an error saying "too many values to unpack", is there a simpler solution which I have no considered? I have looked at many many other solutions but all seem to result in updating a dictionary and accessing key values through a dictionary but I would rather not have to append to a list then update a dictionary with each list.

Comment: it's `for key,value in line.items():` not `keys` !!

Comment: `[{"values":"test","cost":"1234"},{"values":"test2","cost":"12345"}]` is valid json. `json.load()` should give you a list object to iterate through directly from the file, which already contains all of the individual dictionaries as items in that list.

Comment: ok both of these comments really helped, thanks so much guys

Comment: @Dean219 `loads` (with the `s` at the end) is for a string. Rather than going through the file line-by-line and convert lines, just load the whole file in one go with `load()`.

Comment: ah extremely helpful point @roganjosh that may help me reduce my code size. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access both keys and values use the `.items()` method of the dictionary.

```
for key, value in line.items()
```

Also note that the `.keys()` in the first case is not necessary as iterating through a dictionary will normally return its keys.

```
for key in line:
```